# Spammer blacklist request

Tags: feature-request, spam

Recently, we've had several spams linking to gearbikesreview dot com: [1](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/57398/13174), [2](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/57116/first-official-folding-bike-thread-name-your-bike/57117), [3](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/57281) and possibly [4](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/57128/which-caster-board) (the last three of these have been deleted and I don't have enough rep to see them).

Could this site please be blacklisted to prevent the spammer linking to it?

Answer (score 14):

The problem with blacklisting URLs is that spammers immediately get the feedback that they can't post such content, and the ones with any brains will switch to a different URL, or possibly a link shortener.

I've added this URL to the watchlist of [SmokeDetector](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/295232); any new post with this URL, wherever it may be in the network, will be reported in some [chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), where people will ready with their spam flags. Six spam flags will destroy the post and impose an IP block on this user.

(Oh, and don't worry too much about the spammer seeing this post. They're usually too busy spamming across the Internet to read Meta.)